# I can no longer receive messages from whatsapp on my webhook but I do from postman

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-webhooks

I created a webhook to retrieve messages from a whatsapp number.
It had worked very well so far.
Now when I test the webhook on postman it works. But messages from whatsapp are ignored.

NB: I followed the webhook setup of meta for developer with heroku and express.js

when i update the settings on meta it works again but only for a short time

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to initiate the "support window" by first sending a text from your WhatsApp number/phone ***to*** the WhatsApp Business Account.  If 24 hours has elapsed since the WhatsApp user has sent a message to the Business Account, the support window expires and the Business Account can only send templated messages to the end user.  If you attempt to send a non-templated message to an end-user outside of the 24 hour service window, the message will be ignored.

See "User-Initiated Conversations" vs "Business-Initiated Conversations" [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/conversation-types).  And a non-Meta resource [here](https://support.messagebird.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003827698-How-does-messaging-work-on-WhatsApp-Business-).